# How do I load the same iframe multiple times on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Currently, I am loading an iframe on a project several times in a page. This is causing severe performance problems and I ultimately want each iframe to be in sync. This is not happening now because each iframe is loading the page at a different time (milliseconds off). Can I use JavaScript to load an iframe once and then show it in perhaps multiple divs?

Here is what I have so far:

http://gis.kodyahrens.com/AHRENS_SMPRG_SIMPLEPROGRAMTITLE_WEEK14.php

Relevant Code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Grayscale</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <figure class="grayscale">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywCK-vZgpSM?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&VQ=240" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Sepia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <figure class="sepia">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywCK-vZgpSM?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&VQ=240" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Saturate</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <figure class="saturate">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywCK-vZgpSM?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&VQ=240" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some relevant code.

Comment: not sure if you can achieve this, I mean each time you send a request to web, you get a different response.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery's .clone() function, you can clone an element. Give your original iframe an ID and clone it like this:

```
$('#iframeID').clone().appendTo('#someotherdiv');
```